# Nagios Livestatus - Socket python SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal (<string>, line 1)

Tags: python, django, sockets, nagios

Im sending LQL query to Livestatus and sends through a socket.

When im in debug, it works! But when I run without debug, i receive this error:

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal (<string>, line 1)
```

My code is:

```
    len(__nagios_query(('GET services\nFilter: display_name ~~ test\nFilter: state = 0\n')))

def __nagios_query(query):
    ''' Receives the LQL query to Livestatus and sends through a socket.
    Parse the return into lists and dictionaries and return ready to use. '''

    result_list = []
    query += "OutputFormat: python\n"

    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((NG_HOST, NG_PORT))
        s.sendall(query)
        s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)

        answer = s.recv(NG_TIMEOUT)

        s.close()


        result = eval(answer)
        columns = result.pop(0)

        for item in result:
            item = dict(zip(columns, item))
            result_list.append(item)

    except Exception, e:
        raise e

    return result_list
```

With this new line, it works, but not elegant, has another way?

```
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((NG_HOST, NG_PORT))
    s.sendall(query)
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)

    #New line
    time.sleep(0.1)

    answer = s.recv(NG_TIMEOUT)
```

ps: NG_HOST isnt localhost

Comment: Other than the `IndentationError` that will be thrown because of line 1, I don't think there is anything wrong with the code you posted.  The error you generated can only be created by not making a string properly (namely, something like this: `'abc`).  However, all the strings in the code you posted are made correctly.  Something else is the matter.

Comment: The strange is when Im debugging its works...Maybe something synchronous?

Comment: Maybe.  I was just saying there is nothing wrong (at least that I can see) with the posted code.  Everything seems fine, which means the problem is elsewhere.  It might be how you are executing the script, a problem with your installation of Python, really anything.  Just the code is fine.

Comment: Thx.It really is something with the TIME. Look to my edit, it work, but isnt elegant, rsrs.